# Excel Auto-populate

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 40 employees in an Excel spreadsheet 1 in Column A, Rows 2-41.
Column Heading is Employee's Name (in A1).
In Column B, I have a place for his Wage/Hour, but this Column is blank.
I need a formula to take from spreadsheet 2 (having all the employee's name and wages in Columns A and B), their actual wages which are in Column B to auto-populate their wages into spreadsheet 1 column B when I type their name in Column A of spreadsheet 1.
If this can work, I will delete all of the names in Column A, spreadsheet 1. Once it is determined which employees worked on a special project, I will type their name in spreadsheet 1, Column A, and expect that his wages will populate from spreadsheet 2 Column B, into Spreadsheet 1, Column B.

Comment: Please add some relevant linebreaks to improve the readability of your question ...

Answer (score 0):

vlookup("cell with name", "lookup array name and wage", 2, false)

Not sure if your lookup array is a master table containing just latest wage rate or a transaction table containing wage data for every pay period.

Also consider using data validation to create a pulldown list of names so you don't misspell.